# Is there a faster method using Numpy instead of Pandas groupby to calculate the cumulative mean?

Tags: pandas, numpy, performance, optimization, pandas-groupby

I am trying to, as time-efficiently as possible, calculate the cumulative mean for each `Player` when they play a specific `Position` for each stat column. However, as for the specific application I am only focused on past performance, I need to exclude the current value (shift the data once). I have created a list of all the stat columns named `Stats` in order to save time instead of looping through them.

Right now I am using the Pandas group-by function which is sadly too slow for my data. Although the question suggests using Numpy as an alternative, I am really just after the absolute fastest method.

This is my current code, with a minimum reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Player': ['Sam', 'Bob', 'Amy', 'Sam', 'Bob', 'Amy', 'Sam', 'Bob', 'Amy','Sam', 'Bob', 'Amy', 'Sam', 'Bob', 'Amy', 'Sam', 'Bob', 'Amy'],
              'Position': ['Off', 'Def', 'Def', 'Def', 'Off', 'Def', 'Def', 'Off', 'Off', 'Off', 'Def', 'Def', 'Def', 'Off', 'Def', 'Def', 'Off', 'Off'],
              'Stat A': [10, 20, 30, 25, 15, 10, 20, 20, 15, 15, 25, 35, 20, 10, 15, 25, 25, 10],
              'Stat B': [15, 25, 35, 20, 10, 15, 25, 25, 10, 10, 20, 30, 25, 15, 10, 20, 20, 15]})

Stats        = ['Stat A', 'Stat B']

dfgroupby    = df[['Player', 'Position']]

dfshift1     = df.groupby(['Player', 'Position'])[Stats].shift(1)
dfshift2     = pd.concat([dfgroupby, dfshift1], axis = 1)

dfcumsum     = dfshift2.groupby(['Player', 'Position'])[Stats].cumsum()

dfcumcount1  = dfshift2.groupby(['Player', 'Position'])[Stats].cumcount()
dfcumcount2  = pd.concat([dfcumcount1] * len(Stats), axis = 1)

dfcummean1   = pd.DataFrame(dfcumsum.values / dfcumcount2.values, columns = Stats).add_suffix(' - CumMean')
dfcummean2   = pd.concat([dfgroupby, dfcummean1], axis = 1)

dfcummean2
```

Comment: Could you update your example so that it has the same performance problem? The answer may be dependent on size of data. Also - maybe your problem is that you are doing the same thing many times (cumulating from start to t=T, then from start to t=T+1, and so on?)

Comment: What's the size of your actual data? The most efficient method changes depending on the amount of data.